# How to go though exact number of rows using csvkit

Tags: csv, csvkit

I found csvkit very useful tool, but I can't find anywhere in the doc, **how to go through only exact number of rows**. I found only command for searching for rows with specific content.

csvkit docs http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.1/cli.html#input

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to search int the first 100 rows, you can use the `head` command

```
> head -101 foo.csv | csvgrep -c 'col1' -m "bar"
```